# Release excel workbook after write operations through a script

Tags: python, excel-2007

I am using a python script to write data into the excel workbook. Now, I want to release the pointer. I dont want to close the workbook because of some other reasons. I just want to release the pointer. I searched on google but no answer. Can anyone please help?

             `from win32com.client import Dispatch
    xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    xl.ScreenUpdating = True # performance
    xl.Visible = 1
    xl.DisplayAlerts = True
    wbs = xl.Workbooks
    return xl, wbs`
Then i am using wb to refer to workbook's different sheets.
`wb = xl.Workbooks.open(filename)`

Comment: Can you post some of your code you've written so far, or an example that you're looking at? More detail would be helpful here.

Comment: I am using `xlrd` library to work with `excel`.

Comment: @Gauranga You say you are using `xlrd`, but your example code is for `win32com`, so which is it? Your example has a `return` statement but no function definition. Also, what problem are you having that you need to release the pointer?

Answer (score 0):

Variables will be released as they go out of scope. In the example below, the variable `xl` is released when the `get_workbook` function is exited. If you need to explicitly remove a variable, use the `del` statement.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

def get_workbook(path):
    xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    xl.Visible = 1
    return xl.Workbooks.open(path)

wb = get_workbook(r'c:\temp\test.xlsx')
sheet = wb.Worksheets.Item(1)
sheet.Range('A1').Value2 = 'test'

del wb, sheet
```